# SmartSheet API Call Sheets.get_sheet(#) Returns 404 For Existing Sheet ID

Tags: python-3.x, smartsheet-api

Calling:

```
sheet = smart.Sheets.get_sheet(project.task['sheet'])
```

Returns:

```
{"result": {"code": 1006, "errorCode": 1006, "message": "Not Found", "name": "ApiError", "recommendation": "Do not retry without fixing the problem. ", "refId": "1ckyuuv1ngykx", "shouldRetry": false, "statusCode": 404}}
```

I'm an editor, not owner on the sheet, I've re-generated the API token, and I can read other sheets under the same organization and account.  Not sure if its related, the sheet that errors is derived from many other sheets.

Is there a permissions setting or an API access setting on sheets or workspaces that I need to enable?

Comment: Is the value of `project.task['sheet']` a numeric sheet ID?

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify the request first to see if you have access to the sheet:
sheet = smart.Sheets.get_sheet(sheetId)

I'm not sure what you're doing with your code "project.task", so that might be something to look into.

And the other thing I would try is to remove the quotes around the sheetId. I don't think the Python SDK needs those.